# HttpClient throws System.ArgumentException: 'windows-1251' is not a supported encoding name

Tags: c#, character-encoding, windows-phone-8.1, httpclient, windows-1251

I am writing WinPhone 8.1 app. 
Code is very simple and works in most cases:

```
string htmlContent;
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    htmlContent = await client.GetStringAsync(GenerateUri());
}
_htmlDocument.LoadHtml(htmlContent);
```

But sometimes exception is thrown at

```
htmlContent = await client.GetStringAsync(GenerateUri());
```

> InnerException    {System.ArgumentException: 'windows-1251' is not a
>   supported encoding name. Parameter name: name    at
>   System.Globalization.EncodingTable.internalGetCodePageFromName(String
>   name)    at
>   System.Globalization.EncodingTable.GetCodePageFromName(String name)
>   at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpContent.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(Task
>   task)}    System.Exception {System.ArgumentException}

Does HttpClient support 1251 encoding? And if it doesn't, how can I avoid this problem? Or is it target page problem? Or am I wrong in something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Get response as `IBuffer` and then convert using .NET encoding classes:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
IBuffer buffer = await response.Content.ReadAsBufferAsync();
byte[] bytes = buffer.ToArray();

Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251");
string responseString = encoding.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! The only difference was:                                   `byte[] bytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();`

Comment: @HarrySmith or even simpler `var bytes = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(uri);`